# Oracle {LIST} Partition by Program and {RANGE} subpartition by DATE with interval

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle12c, partitioning, database-partitioning

I'm trying to figure the best possible way to determine the partition strategy in Oracle 12c (12.2.0.1.0) 
This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34029035/oracle-partition-by-id-and-subpartition-by-date-with-interval) 
is almost identical to my requirements. However, I want to know the best possible way to implement in Oracle 12c (12.2.0.1.0) version.

Here is my question:
We have four (4) distinct programs for which the bills are submitted in our system.

The approx volume of bills submitted per year is as follows: 
Program_1  ~ 3M   per   year 
Program_2  ~ 1M   per   year 
Program_3  ~ 500K per year 
Program_4  ~ 100K per year

My initial thought process is to create PARTITION BY LIST (PROGRAM) AND SUBPARTITION BY RANGE (BILL_SUBMISSION_DATE).

I would like to use oracle interval feature for SUBPARTITION, would like to know if there are any limitations with this approach.

Answer (score 0):

Your approach of partitioning by `PROGRAM` and sub-partitioning by `BILL_SUBMISSTION_DATE` sounds good.

I have not tested performance differences (I imagine they would be negligible), but for coding the `INTERVAL` option makes querying and maintenance easier in my opinion.

For the following example the table partition clause I used was:

```
partition by range (INVOICE_MONTH) interval (numtoyminterval(1, 'MONTH'))
```

Example query, using old style partition names, query a partition for an invoice for April 2012, assuming I created a partition named `INV201204` for those invoices for that month:

```
select * from MARK_INV_HDR
    partition ('INV201204');
```

And the same query, using `INTERVAL` automatically generated partitions:

```
select * from MARK_INV_HDR 
    where invoice_month = to_date('2012-04', 'yyyy-mm');
```

The advantage of the later query is I don't have to know the naming convention for the partitions.

To drop the oldest partition, one query and one DDL:

```
select to_char(min(invoice_month), 'dd-Mon-yyyy') as min_inv_dt from MARK_INV_HDR;

MIN_INV_DT
-----------
01-Apr-2012

alter table mark_inv_hdr 
    drop partition for (TO_DATE('01-Apr-2012', 'dd-Mon-yyyy'))
    update global indexes;
```

EDIT:

Update:  I forgot that you cannot use the `INTERVAL` clause on a sub-partition; thanks to user12283435 for the reminder.  In looking more closely at the question, it appears that there is probably no need to partition on `PROGRAM`, so just a single partition by range on `BILL_SUBMISSION_DATE` with the `INTERVAL` clause should work fine.

When you have a small set of values like you do for `PROGRAM`, no obvious reason to partition on it.  The typical example of partitioning by list given in Oracle documentation is list of regions, for a global call center, so that you can do batch reports and maintenance on certain regions after business hours, etc.  You can have a global bit-mapped index on `PROGRAM`, if you don't do many updates, if you query criteria frequently includes just one `PROGRAM`.  (Updating a column with a bit-mapped index will briefly lock the table.)

Comment: Thanks Mark.  Looks like Oracle does not allow interval at `subpartition` level.  Does this mean we've to manually create the `partitions` and `subpartitions`?

Comment: Oh, yeah; forgot about that.... thinking about it a bit more, the `PROGRAM` column is probably not really necessary to partition by, so you could just partition on `BILL_SUBMISSION_DATE` using the `INTERVAL` clause, and no sub-partition needed.  I'll try and update my answer in my spare time with a bit more reasoning.